# Tracking Dynamic Weekly and Monthly Sales/Purchases given a fixed start date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle SQL programming (programming in general actually) and recently discovered analytical functions. I am convinced I can use them to automate my daily, weekly, and monthly reporting.

I need help tracking week-on-week and month-on-month sales and purchases given a particular date as the start of the year or and/or week.

I have a table that maintains daily sales and purchases transactions by sales agents, how do I dynamically track revenue growth (since the year began) for week-on-week as well as month-on-month purchases per territory per region from our transactions table.

Our reporting week runs from Wednesday through Tuesday. I have managed to get some output(albeit not entirely accurate) for month-on-month but week-on-week is challenging me. How do maintain a dynamic counter of days in Oracle SQL that refreshes and starts another week each time it adds up to 7 days across the entire daily transactions table?

The interesting challenge I have in my head that I can't seem to put into code is what happens when I have a partial week's worth of data?! I want to be able to compare, say, 3 days worth of the current week's transactions with 3 days worth of the previous week's transactions. The same can be said for a partial month's worth of data.

This is the month-on-month analysis code I have managed so far.

```
WITH

monthly_revenue as (

SELECT
to_char(txn_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month_key,
sum(stock_purchased) as revenue
FROM transactions_table
GROUP BY  to_char(date_key, 'YYYY-MM')
),

prev_month_revenue as (

SELECT 
month_key, revenue, lag(revenue) over (order by month_key) as 
prev_month_revenue
FROM monthly_revenue
)

SELECT month_key,revenue,prev_month_revenue, round(100.0*(revenue- 
prev_month_revenue)/prev_month_revenue,1) as revenue_growth
FROM prev_month_revenue

ORDER BY month_key;
```

The structure of my table is as below:

`txn_date DATE,
 agent_id NUMBER(12),
 supervisor_id NUMBER(12),
 stock_purchased NUMBER(15),
 stock_sold NUMBER(15),
 no_of_txns NUMBER(15),
 account_balance NUMBER(15)`

I would like to have my output in the format below;

`Week-Start | Week-End | Week_Purchases | Previous_Week_Purchases | % Growth`

If I can get over the initial hurdle of tracking week-on-week purchases and sales, I can easily attach location information.

Comment: In your desired output, what month do you want displayed when the week has days from two months in it? E.g. the week of 6/27/2018.

Comment: @kfinity I hadn't realized that. Thanks for the catch. I have edited the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trunc function truncates a date to the specified unit. By default this is the day. But you can also use it to get the start of the previous week/month/quarter/year.

The format iw returns the start of the ISO week. Which is a Monday.

So how does that help you with weeks running Weds-Tues?

Subtract two from your date before passing it to trunc and voila!

```
with rws as (
  select date'2018-07-24'+level dt from dual
  connect by level <= 14
)
  select * from rws;

DT            
25-JUL-2018   
26-JUL-2018   
27-JUL-2018   
28-JUL-2018   
29-JUL-2018   
30-JUL-2018   
31-JUL-2018   
01-AUG-2018   
02-AUG-2018   
03-AUG-2018   
04-AUG-2018   
05-AUG-2018   
06-AUG-2018   
07-AUG-2018 

with rws as (
  select date'2018-07-24'+level dt from dual
  connect by level <= 14
)
  select trunc ( dt-2, 'iw' ),
         to_char ( min ( dt ), 'DY' ) week_start_day,
         to_char ( max ( dt ), 'DY' ) week_end_day
  from   rws
  group  by trunc ( dt-2, 'iw' )
  order  by trunc ( dt-2, 'iw' );

TRUNC(DT-2,'IW')   WEEK_START_DAY   WEEK_END_DAY   
23-JUL-2018        WED              TUE            
30-JUL-2018        WED              TUE
```

Regarding:

*I want to be able to compare, say, 3 days worth of the current week's transactions with 3 days worth of the previous week's transactions*

I'm not sure what you're asking here. But you can use the windowing clause of analytic functions to get values that fall in a specific offset from the current. For example, the following calculates two running total. The first over the past three days. The second the corresponding three days in the previous week:

```
with rws as (
  select date'2018-07-24'+level dt , 
         round ( dbms_random.value( 1, 100 ) ) val
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select dt, val, 
         sum ( val ) over ( 
           order by dt range between 3 preceding and current row 
         ) past_three, 
         sum ( val ) over ( 
           order by dt range between 10 preceding and 7 preceding 
         ) three_prev_week
  from   rws
  order  by dt;

DT            VAL   PAST_THREE   THREE_PREV_WEEK   
25-JUL-2018       5            5            <null> 
26-JUL-2018      89           94            <null> 
27-JUL-2018      34          128            <null> 
28-JUL-2018      88          216            <null> 
29-JUL-2018      48          259            <null> 
30-JUL-2018      25          195            <null> 
31-JUL-2018      19          180            <null> 
01-AUG-2018      71          163                 5 
02-AUG-2018      12          127                94 
03-AUG-2018      39          141               128
```